# Place check boxes into multiple columns

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

So for a custom list, I have a choice field with 50 options for the user to select which States. However this causes the edit form of the item to look a little wonky as all 50 checkboxes for the states are listed in one column. Is there anyway to split these into 5 columns with 10 states in each on the edit form.

Following is my code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
columnName: "State",
perRow: 2
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this SPServices. The `$().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices` [method](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices&referringTitle=Documentation) lets you define how many to put in a row.

Comment: Do I just add the script to a CEWP on my edit form?

Comment: I create an html file in a library and link the CEWP to that... I find that sometimes the CEWP messes up scripts.

Comment: Worked in chrome, but no change in IE for whatever reason!

Comment: Will you add your code to your post?